# Run shell command from Ruby without it prefixing gem directory to my $PATH

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I'm attempting to run Vagrant via a Ruby script by shelling out via backticks

`` `vagrant up` ``

This doesn't work when run through Ruby because the shell has a modified $PATH env var prefixed with the path to my gems (/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/bin). This means that its trying to invoke vagrant from the installed gem instead of the installed version in /usr/bin.

My Ruby runtime has the system gem path prepended because my rakefile is requiring 'bundler/setup'. It turns out [Bundler is modifying](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/de770f1be22dbae83ac0f651e0a74d207e72c227/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L221) my PATH environment variable.

Comment: Modify the path in your `ENV['PATH']` variable prior to shelling?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I did find that "require 'bundler/setup'" in my Rakefile was the cause of the additional gem dir in my PATH. Why does bundler do that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

it's not pretty, but `set Path=#{ENV['Path']}&&vagrant up`

Comment: My $PATH env var already has the gem path prefixed once I start Ruby, so this doesn't help. Not sure if this its Rake that is adding it or what, because irb and a vanilla Ruby script does not do this.